Comparing Nではないだろうか and Nなのではないだろうか
According to bunpro, the structure of ではないだろうか with a noun is

Noun + （なの）+ ではない（だろう）か

It seems like the なの part is optional. So, I wonder if there is any difference between Noun+ではないだろうか and Noun+なのではないだろうか. I think the latter gives much more weaker certainty than the former. This is similar to the difference between Nではないか and Nなのではないか. Is that right?

No, the degree of certainty is not important. This の is an explanatory-の, so it is used based on how closely the sentence is related to the current situation or existing question. If the noun (N) serves as an explanation of some previous context, の is used. Otherwise, の is not used.
For an English speaker, the difference is often explained as follows:

Nではないだろうか?
Isn't it N?
Nなのではないだろうか?
Isn't it that it's N?

Of course, English speakers don't say the latter often, so they find it difficult to understand the necessity of this kind of の. However, it is a fundamental expression in Japanese, and you have to master its use.
For example, の is typically not used in the following case because there is no previous context:

あそこにいる人は誰だろう？ 佐藤さんではないだろうか？
Who is that person over there? Could it be Sato-san?

But after a long discussion about who is the best person to be a leader, you would probably say:

...結局、リーダーになるべきなのは、佐藤さんなのではないだろうか？
...at the end of the day, isn't it Sato-san who should be our leader?

There is no clear-cut criteria, so you may have to get used to its usage and nuance through a lot of examples.
